# Does there exist an entangled quantum state with zero quantum discord?

Tags: quantum-information

Quantum discord is usually considered as a quantum correlation weaker than quantum entanglement. There are separable (non-entangled) quantum states with non-zero quantum discord. Ideas of entanglement and discord come from two different points of view. My question is if there is an entangled state with zero quantum discord. If such a state does not exist, then why?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expression of the quantum discord depend on two subsytem $A$ and $B$.

Quantum discord is zero only for quantum-classical states. Meaning states with density matrix of the form $\sum_i p_i \rho_i^A \otimes |i\rangle \langle i|^B$. Where the $|i \rangle$ are orthogonal. See by exemple the original paper by Zurek https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0011039 (p. 861). Or the reference in the comment (thanks), which is maybe clearer.

A separable state will be of the form $\sum_i w_i \rho_i^A \otimes \rho_i^B$ where both $\rho$ are pure.

Hence no, there's no state which is entangled with zero quantum discord.

Comment: Kindly provide proper reference to the paper you have mentioned.

Comment: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1411.3208v1.pdf has references to original Zurek papers.

Comment: @Dutta Maybe refer to the paper 'Unified view of quantum and classical correlations', where you see clearly the answer.